# Ошибки при запуске apk собранной через Buildozer kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Пробую собрать тестовое приложение по этой статье на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/479236/).
Приложение собралось без ошибок. После установки на телефон сразу же вылетает. С помощью  `buildozer android logcat` выдает такую **ошибку**:

```
07-01 14:29:30.644 17929 17985 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
07-01 14:29:30.644 17929 17985 I python  : AND: Ran string
07-01 14:29:30.644 17929 17985 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
07-01 14:29:30.750 17929 17985 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
07-01 14:29:30.750 17929 17985 I python  :   File "/home/vadim/TestKivyMD/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
07-01 14:29:30.750 17929 17985 I python  :   File "/home/vadim/TestKivyMD/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/kivytest/kivy/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
07-01 14:29:30.751 17929 17985 I python  : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.logger'
07-01 14:29:30.751 17929 17985 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, вам нужно в дополнительные модули в файле buildozer.init прописать kivy.logger